# Custom Plugin for hawtio 2.x

Tags: hawtio

I am trying to write a custom plugin for hawtio 2.x.

The first step that I tried building the entire project (https://github.com/hawtio/hawtio) as instructed in https://github.com/hawtio/hawtio/blob/master/BUILDING.md

Later, I tried the example (springboot sample) located at https://github.com/hawtio/hawtio/tree/master/examples/springboot

The example seems to run fine, except for the fact that I do not see a trace of the sample plugin written in this application (https://github.com/hawtio/hawtio/blob/master/examples/springboot/src/main/webapp/app/sample-plugin/js/sample-plugin.js)

Right now, I am not trying to do fancy stuffs. I am simply trying to run this sample application and see how the plugin works.

Below is the screenshot of the web console. I have also checked in the browser console. I do not see any traces of the initialization of this plugin.

[image: Screenshot of the app]

Am I missing something specific?

Comment: I did get this sample-plugin working in hawtio. When it is working, you will see it show up on the main menu on the left with name 'Sample Plugin'. I just copied the code from the example link you referenced.